# Why display flex has no effect on body in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have simple square divs which I'm using them as component but when I'm applying `display:flex` to `body` it's not working , in normal situation my divs should be next together. I even tried to make container for my components but didn't work.

```
import React from "react";
import Myfunc from "./CSSexample";
function App(){
    return(
       <div>
         <Myfunc/>
         <Myfunc/>
         <Myfunc/>
         <Myfunc/>
       </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: `display:flex` works fine on the `body` element, but since you only have one root element (the `<div>` containing each of the `Myfunc` component) it will only affect that single element.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display: flex` to a parent `<div>`, not to the `body`. So:

```
import React from "react";
import Myfunc from "./CSSexample";
function App(){
    return(
       <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
         <Myfunc/>
         <Myfunc/>
         <Myfunc/>
         <Myfunc/>
       </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: actually no ... I want to apply this on body tag but it's not working with inline flex. they are not aligning next to each other